# Como realizar pull automático com Git?

Tags: git, github, gulpjs

Imagine que eu tenha um ambiente para teste de um aplicativo web, onde existe um repositório clonado do GitHub que fica direto dentro do servidor, sendo que qualquer modificação nele já resulta em uma modificação em tempo real quando o usuário acessar o mesmo via navegador.

Minha dúvida é, existe alguma forma de adicionar um *listener* neste repositório local de forma que sempre que houver alteração no repositório oficial (GitHub) ele já baixe as alterações automaticamente? Ilustração para facilitar o entendimento:

[image]

Andei pesquisando e não encontrei nada a respeito, mas sei que para atualizar meu repositório local, o comando seria:

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Existe alguma solução do próprio Git ou em Gulp para este tipo de *listener*?

Comment: Não sei se seria o caso, mas já pensou em uma tarefa do cron para isso? Outra opção seria procurar por hooks do Git.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É possível usar um [*web hook*](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) fornecido pela [API do Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/). Ele é o seu *listener*.

[Documentação](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) do Git para configuração de ganchos.

Para conseguir o que deseja de forma bem automática precisará escrever um *script*. [Um exemplo](https://github.com/logsol/Github-Auto-Deploy).

Um exemplo simples:

Crie um *script* que faça o *pull*. Exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
cd ~/project
git pull
```

Registre o URL deste *script* no Github na opção `Webhooks & Services` (no `Settings`) criando um novo *webhook* e aceitando tudo como o padrão. Ele será chamado quando ocorrer uma alteração no repositório.

No fundo a única ação realmente necessária no *script* é o `git pull`. Aí depende de como você quer fazer o *deploy* e como seu Git está configurado.

Obviamente o *script* precisa estar acessível por HTTP e a devida permissão de execução é necessária.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então se eu entendi bem é o próprio *Webhook* que irá acessar uma URL minha que dispararia a ação que eu quero, correto?

Comment: Exatamente. Seu *script* é a ação a ser executada pelo evento do Github. O *script* é quem assina o evento e fica escutando quando ele tem algo pra te falar. Claro que o *script* será executado no seu servidor.