# O que é um Webhook?

Tags: terminologia

Vi algumas perguntas aqui que falam sobre o termo o *Webhook*. Gostaria de saber melhor do que se trata esse termo na programação.

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44760/101

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB3M0.png

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Os Webhooks são, basicamente, um meio de comunicação entre suas aplicações. Com eles, uma aplicação é capaz de enviar dados à outras aplicações. Desse modo, webhooks enviam dados mediante o acontecimento de um evento específico, geralmente em tempo real. Em suma, um autêntico *callback* estabelecido através do protocolo HTTP.

A aplicação que implementou o webhook irá enviar requisições HTTP às aplicações que se inscreveram. Por esse motivo, também são chamados de "*web callbacks*" ou "*reverse API*".

Como o *webhook* enviará uma requisição HTTP à outras aplicações, se a sua aplicação irá "receber" os dados, ela deverá estar preparada para receber e interpretar os dados, que geralmente são enviados sob o método POST com um [payload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188469/69296) em JSON. A aplicação receptora configurará, desse modo, um *endpoint* HTTP (geralmente no método POST), para receber os dados.

[image: Diagrama de Webhook]

Acima temos um simples diagrama para exemplificar o funcionamento de um webhook. Nesse caso, "Twitter Server" é a aplicação que enviará os webhooks e "Your Server" é a aplicação que irá recebê-los. Dessa maneira, mediante o acontecimento de eventos no Twitter, a sua aplicação receberá requisições HTTP (os webhooks), enviadas pelo Twitter. Por isso, a aplicação que receberá esses *callbacks* deve estar preparada para lidar e interpretar essas requisições.

Há também formas de autenticação no meio de webhooks. Como a aplicação que irá receber os dados deverá manter um *endpoint* para receber os dados da aplicação que enviará o *webhook*, pessoas com más intenções podem usar esse *endpoint* para enviar informações falsas. Desse modo, algum meio de autenticação poderá ser configurado entre as duas aplicações para que esse problema seja evitado. Entre os meios mais comuns de autenticação, podem ser citados:

- A criação de uma lista-branca com IPs pré-configurados;
- Autenticação [HTTP Basic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254503/69296);
- Tokens diversos, que podem ser incluídos em cabeçalhos HTTP. O GitHub, [por exemplo](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/#validating-payloads-from-github), utiliza essa técnica.

#### Webhook × API

Muitas pessoas confundem webhooks com APIs. No entanto, apesar de fornecerem dados à um cliente, fazem isso de formas distintas. Basicamente, um webhook irá enviar os dados para as aplicações *inscritas* em tempo real (em "*push*"), enquanto uma API irá enviar os dados quando forem solicitados pelo cliente.

Além disso, o propósito das APIs é fornecer uma extensa quantidade de ferramentas para os clientes, como um CRUD. Os webhooks, por outro lado, na maioria das vezes tem a função de notificar o acontecimento de um evento, podendo também enviar dados relativos ao evento. [Há um artigo em Inglês que elabora bem mais essas diferenças.](https://hackernoon.com/webhook-vs-api-whats-the-difference-8d41e6661652)

#### Referência

Recursos que usei para elaborar essa resposta:

- [Webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook);
- [What's a Webhook?](https://sendgrid.com/blog/whats-webhook/)

Answer (score 8):

Um Webhook é uma forma de permitir que seja executada uma ação após o acontecimento de um evento.

Geralmente é utilizado para permitir que aplicações externas possam se utilizar dos dados de um evento no exato momento em que ele acontece.

Exemplos disso seriam por exemplo a integração do github com o slack, do trello com o discord, e por aí vai.

O conceito resume-se em:
  - Uma parte que proverá esses dados, e portanto precisa permitir que sejam cadastrados os "listeners" para os eventos selecionados
  - Uma outra parte que saberá utilizar essas informações da forma como for desejada

Answer (score -3):

Webhook é uma forma de receber informações, e elas só são passadas quando ocorre um evento.Na prática, é uma forma de troca de informações entre dois sistemas, mas apenas quando há de fato uma informação a ser passada. É uma maneira prática para um app ou sistema fornecer informações em tempo real.

Você pode conhecer o webhook também como um retorno de chamada HTTP.

Nesse link [aqui](https://blog.vindi.com.br/o-que-sao-webhooks/) você pode encontrar mais detalhes até de como criar ou implementar um webhook.

Answer (score -6):

Webhook é um recurso que envia informações em tempo real, tornando o desenvolvimento de sistemas mais fácil.

Neste link você poderá saber mais sobre webhook.
link: https://blog.tecnospeed.com.br/webhook-o-que-e/

Answer (score -6):

Um webhook em desenvolvimento Web é um método de ampliar ou alterar o comportamento de uma página da Web, ou aplicação da Web, com callbacks personalizados.